# HTML/CSS/JS - How to resize absolute positioned images?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a webpage that consists mostly of various images absolutely positioned as to make a collage. Right now if the user resizes the window parts of the page go off screen and a horizontal scroll bar comes out.

Is there a way to make it so on resize the entire collage scales proportionally, such that the entire collage is always visible and that the position remains correct? JS/JQuery solutions acceptable.

Thanks!

```css
body {
    background: #fddfef;
    font-family: 'Averia Serif Libre', cursive;
}
a{
    color: #fea6d5;
}
.header{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    clear:both;
}
.footer{
    text-align: center;
    background: #fddfef;
    /*font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;*/
    font-size: .5em;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
}
.Imagecontainerbg{
    position: relative;
    bottom: 3em;
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}
.Imagecontainerbg img{
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}
.Imagecontainerbg img:hover{
    transform: scale(1.03);
}
#grass{
    position: absolute;
    top: 13.7em;
    left: 0.9em;
}
#fanguitar{
    position: absolute;
    top: 10.7em;
    left: 11.5em;  
}
#twodudes{
    position: absolute;
    top: 41.0em;
    left: 13.5em;   
}
#kid{
    position: absolute;
    top: 35.3em;
    left: 26.8em;  
}
#equipment{
    position: absolute;
    top: 11.7em;
    left: 28.8em; 
}
#fish{
    position: absolute;
    top: 20.5em;
    left: 45.8em;  
}
#pipe{
    position: absolute;
    top: 5.0em;
    left: 60.8em; 
}
#jesus{
    position: absolute;
    top: 29.8em;
    left: 60.8em; 
}

.biocolumn {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    top:22.0em;
    left: 0.9em;
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}
.biocolumn:not(.biocontent > p):hover{
    z-index: 1;
    transform: scale(1.01);
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;
}
.bioimg:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;
}
.musiccolumn {
    position: absolute;
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    top:22.9em;
    left: 29em;
}
.musiccolumn:hover{
    transform: scale(1.02);
    z-index: 1;
}
.tourcolumn {
    position: absolute;
    top:33em;
    left: 42em;
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}
.tourcolumn:not(.tourcontent > p):hover{
     z-index: 1;
    transform: scale(1.02);
}
.tourimg:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;
}
.contactcolumn{
    position: absolute;
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    top:18em;
    left: 60.5em;  
}
.contactcolumn:hover{
    transform: scale(1.02);
}
.albumcolumn{
    position: absolute;
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    top:8.0em;
    left: 42.0em;    
}
.albumcolumn:hover{
    z-index: 0;
    transform: scale(1.02);
}
.biocontent{
    display: none;
    width:320px;
    text-align: left;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 1em;
    left:30em; 
    bottom: 20.6em; 
}
.tourcontent{
    display: none;
    width:320px;
    text-align: left;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 1em;
    top: -23em; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <!-- Fonts -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Averia+Serif+Libre" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!--  Meta  -->
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title></title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
  <!--  Styles  -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0">

</head>
<body>
<div class="header"><a href="index.html"><img src="images/signature.png" id="headerimg"></a></div>
<div class="Imagecontainerbg">
<!--<img src="images/bg.png" class="bgimage">-->
<!--<img src="images/grass.jpg" id="grass"> -->
<img src="images/fanguitar.jpg" id="fanguitar"> 
<!--<img src="images/twodudes.jpg" id="twodudes">-->
<img src="images/kid.jpg" id="kid">
<img src="images/equipment.jpg" id="equipment">
<img src="images/fish.jpg" id="fish">
<img src="images/pipe.jpg" id="pipe">
<img src="images/jesus.jpg" id="jesus">
<div class="biocolumn">
    <img src="images/bio.jpg" class="bioimg">
     <div class="biocontent">
      <p class="about">The product of a suburban New England upbringing, where he discovered the joys of balanced breakfasts and quiet nights spent under the stars, Emmett McCleary writes earnest music for earnest people. Informed by 60s and 70s pop, his songwriting is direct without being obvious, and at its best recalls songsmiths like Neil Finn and Elliott Smith. His debut LP There’s a Better Something was recorded at home between semesters at Montréal’s McGill University; as of winter 2017 McCleary is readying the album for release and feels ambivalent about his arts degree. Emmett makes a mean Bolognese sauce and does not smoke cigarettes.</p>
    </div> 
</div>
   
<div class="tourcolumn">
    <img src="images/tour.jpg" class="tourimg">
    <div class="tourcontent">
      <p class="tourdates">Tour Date<br>etc2<br>etc3<br>etc4<br>etc5</p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="musiccolumn">
    <a href="" target="_blank"><img src="images/music.jpg" class="musicimg"></a>
</div>
<div class="musiccolumn">
    <a href="" target="_blank"><img src="images/music.jpg" class="musicimg"></a>
</div>
<div class="albumcolumn">
<a href="TBD"><img src="images/album.jpg" class="albumimg"></a>
</div>
<div class="contactcolumn">
    <a href="mailto:test.com"><img src="images/contact.jpg" class="contactimg"></a>
</div>
</div>
    
<div class="footer">
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/emmettmccleary/" target="_blank"><img src="images/facebook.png" height="15" width="15"></a>&nbsp;
    <a href="https://www.instagram.com/emmettmccleary/" target="_blank"><img src="images/instagram.png" height="15" width="15"></a>&nbsp;
    <a href="https://twitter.com/emmettmccleary" target="_blank"><img src="images/twitter.png" height="15" width="15"></a>
    
    <p>&copy; Footer </a>.</p></div>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I would wrap everything in a container and listen for window resize then change the width of the container when window is resized.

Comment: @garek007 It's so much simpler just setting a common width and height in % form.

Comment: @TyQ. you are right. That was my thought at first too, then for some reason I went the JQuery route. I totally spaced that you could just do this with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You need add all images inside the container's div (container with position:relative), and positioning all images with % (with position absolute) otherwise of em, and change all image sizes (width) to percentage and height to auto... So when you resize the screen, all images keep on "same place...", the images got resize according window size like responsive website.